# Unable to upload the images to mySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Still a newb to coding . have almost no idea what im doing . i tried to make a php page which would let me upload and view an image . do not know what is wrong . i tried to do it as correctly as possible . could someone please help me out ?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="file" name="image"></input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload"></input>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
echo "button has been clicked";
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","demo");
if(!$con)
echo "didnt connect to database ";
else echo "connected ";
$imagename= mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES['image'] ['name']);
$imagefile =mysqli_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$qry = "INSERT INTO image (name,file) VALUES ('$imagename','$imagefile')";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
if($result)
echo "image has been uploaded";
viewimage();
function viewimage()
{$recon = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","demo");
 $view = "SELECT * FROM image ";
$data =mysqli_query($recon,$view);
$res2 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
$currimage =$res2['file'];
echo "$currimage <br/>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to close the `<form>` tag before you start your php code. Also I'd suggest breaking the code up so its easier to read, super jumbled at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to catch a post variable, you need to submit the form and handle the action. The first problem with your code is that your form is not complete - it's missing a closing tag. Second thing, to be able to send a file through the post, you'll need multipart form. You should add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as an attribute of the form.
So, instead of

```
 <form method="post">
 <input type="file" name="image"></input>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload"></input>
```

You'll need

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="image"></input>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must move the uploaded image to server 
try this code -- create directory /uploads/

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image"></input>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload"></input>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    echo "button has been clicked";
    $con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","demo");
    if(!$con)
    echo "didnt connect to database ";
    else echo "connected";
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
 $tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
        $name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    $qry = "INSERT INTO image (name,file) VALUES ('$name','$tmp_name')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
    if($result)
    echo "image has been uploaded";
    viewimage();
    function viewimage()
    {$recon = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","demo");
        $view = "SELECT * FROM image ";
    $data =mysqli_query($recon,$view);
    $res2 =mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
    $currimage =$res2['file'];
    echo '<img src="'.$currimage.'" /> <br/>';
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ill post a new question with the modified code and errors cause its still not working for me